# create intro thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing a thesis and I would create an intro that should go into table of contents. Any idea how to put it into table of contents?

this is my code

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\Huge \textbf{Intro}}

\bigskip

\bigskip

\lipsum[1]
```

EDIT

This is my table of contents

Table of Contents

Figures

Tables

Intro <- Here where I want put my intro

1 Chapter 1
 1.1 section

Comment: At which level? `\addcontentsline{toc}{<level>}{<text>}` where `<level>` is `part`, `chapter`, … and `<text>` could be `Intro`. (Or just plain `\chapter{Intro}`?) This could also be something for an `abstract` environment or macro.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you can try /frontmatter.

Comment: after you put \chapter*{Intro} and afetr \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro}

Comment: @maria Please, can you provide a minimal, but complete, code as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction} % what looks better section or chapter?
\section*{Introduction} % * prevents the numbering. We already added it manually to toc above
\chapter{Theory}
\chapter{Experiment}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example for Introduction]

## thanks to the comment I found a better solution in the book [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehtYM.jpg):

use one of the commands

```
\addpart[short]{long headline}
\addpart*{long headline}
\addchap[short]{long headline}
\addchap*{long headline}
\addsec[short]{long headline}
\addsec*{long headline}
```

#### Working example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addpart[Day 1]{Day one}
\addsec*{Introduction}
\addchap{Theory}
\addpart[Experiments]{Nice experiments}
\end{document}
```

[image: Koma Script] **Page 115** in Kohm, Markus und Morawski, Jens-Uwe:
KOMA-Script - Die Anleitung;
DANTE e.V., Lehmanns Media, 4., erweiterte Aufl. 2012
592 Seiten
(ISBN 978-3-86541-459-5;

Comment: Why not `\addsec{Introduction}` that avoids the need to use `\addcontentsline`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is the solution with `\frontmatter` command:

```
%& --translate-file=utf-8
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro}

Some text 

\mainmatter

\chapter{FIRST}
 Some more text

\backmatter

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the frontmatter, you may simply use `\chapter{Intro}` (the non-starred version), as `\frontmatter` switches off chapter numbering.

Comment: @lockstep when I use non-starred version, there is two "Intro" lines in TOC.

Comment: Of course, you should remove `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro}`.

Comment: @lockstep Of course :)